# Vim keybindings in Jupyter/Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I've started using the `vim` shortcuts in Google Colab. It's great when it works, but it seems to be hit-or-miss with the features that are supported. When I press `/` I get a search-like command prompt:

[image]

And doing the `:` command gives me what seems like the `vim` command-line mode:

[image]

However, other than the `s`(ubstitute) command, it doesn't seem like anything else works:

[image]

Is there any documentation on what's supported here? Where could I find it? The current setting I have enabled is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Check out one of [these](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+vim)

Comment: @Hedy -- that's a good start, but is there any information on what is there now?

Comment: Seems that basic editing commands should work, but I don't see why you need `:echo` when working in a jupyter notebook

Comment: @Hedy -- of course I don't, I was just showing that as a basic command that isn't there. Though something like `d` or `g` is pretty useful, so I just tried a bunch and `s` seemed like the only one that worked.